# CSS background image cropping issue

Tags: html, css

Link:
[Image Cropped Preview](http://ec2-52-66-146-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/Purvi/index.php/RO/ro_view/5)

In my HTML page is not showing full image and I want to show it full without cropping How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

what about `background-size: contain;` ?

Comment: Not working. I didn't want to resize the image. The image must be the same size but it can be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this css:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```